# List of same 13 characters in a row Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, input, character

So far for my code, I have:

```
while True:
    """
    determines if there is a list of x's or o's in a horizontal row
    """
    game = list(input())
    if len(game) == 0:
        print("We should now check for vertical or diagonal winners!")
    elif game[0] == game[1]:
        if game[1] == game[2]:
            if game[2] == game[3]:
                if game[3] == game[4]:
                    if game[4] == game[5]:
                        if game[5] == game[6]:
                            if game[6] == game[7]:
                                if game[7] == game[8]:
                                    if game[8] == game[9]:
                                        if game[9] == game[10]:
                                            if game[10] == game[11]:
                                                if game[11] == game[12]:
                                                    if game[12] == "o":
                                                        print("Player o won")
                                                    else:
                                                        print("Player x won")
                                                else:
                                                    del game[0:12]
                                            else:
                                                del game[0:12]
                                        else:
                                            del game[0:12]
                                    else:
                                        del game[0:12]
                                else:
                                    del game[0:12]
                            else:
                                del game[0:12]
                        else:
                            del game[0:12]
                    else:
                        del game[0:12]
                else:
                    del game[0:12]
            else:
                del game[0:12]
        else:
            del game[0:12]
    else:
        del game[0:12]
```

I feel like there has to be a shorter way to write this. I also have only thought of a way to determine if there is a horizontal winner. I'm not sure how to go about solving for vertical or diagonal winners. I also tested this code with x winning in the second row, and it didn't print that x won, so I'm wondering where my error is?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you learned about loops yet?  If not, this would be a good time to.

Comment: Why has this been tagged 'recursion'?

Comment: @ScottHunter because from algorithmic point of view the simplest solution is recursive?

Comment: I don't really understand the code you have so far (you're absolutely right, there _has_ to be an easier way to do that, but since I can't quite figure out what it is you want to do, all I can tell you for right now is that the del keyword doesn't work on strings.

Comment: 1) first make this a matrix (list of lists); 2) notice, that to check if all characters in list `lst` are equal to `ch` (lets call this function `all_are(lst, char)`) is the same as saying that `lst[0] == ch and all_are(lst[1:], ch)`; so you can solve this resursively.

Answer (score 2):

You badly need to learn about regex my man!

This seems pretty suspiciously like a homework question, but since others are answering anyway...I'll give you the fastest answer :-).  Regex will probably be faster than anything you write in pure python for this problem because it uses compiled c code.

You can test for horizontal or vertical matches fairly easily directly from the input string using regex.

```
import re

# find 13 x's or o's in a row that begin some multiple of 13 characters from the beginning of the input string
horizMatch_regex = re.compile("^(.{13})*(xxxxxxxxxxxxx|ooooooooooooo)")
# find 13 x's or o's that appear with exactly 12 characters in between, which corresponds to columns.  Requires lookahead (?=) 
verticalMatch_regex = re.compile("(x(.{12})(?=x)){12}|(o(.{12})(?=o)){12}")
# slightly trickier - you need 4 separate match groups to test for each possible diagonal.  There are a variety of ways to do that, but here's one
diagonalMatch_regex = re.compile("(^(x.{13}){12}x)|(^(o.{13}){12}o)|((x.{11}){13}.$)|((o.{11}){13}.$)")

if horizMatch_regex.search(input_str):
    print("We have a horizontal tic tac toe!")

if verticalMatch_regex.search(input_str):
    print("We have a vertical tic tac toe!")

if diagonalMatch_regex.search(input_str):
    print("We have a diagonal tic tac toe!")

# string with horizontal, vertical, and diagonal tic tac toe's
input_str = "xooooooooooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxxoxoooooooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxoxoooxoooooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxoxoooooxoooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxoxoooooooxoooxxxxxxxxxxxxxoxoooooooooxoxxxxxxxxxxxxxoxooooooooooox"

We have a horizontal tic tac toe!
We have a vertical tic tac toe!
We have a diagonal tic tac toe!
```

Comment: well...ok that's a good point.  But my thinking was if I explain it, solving the diagonal would be too easy.  I'll probably just go ahead and post the whole answer though, b/c I'm a softee

Comment: The statement "Regex will be faster than anything you write in pure python because it uses compiled c code" is false. Certain regexes can run into problems (e.g. catastrophic backtracking), and Python itself makes quite a bit of use of C libraries (in regex and other areas).

Comment: Obviously regex can be quite slow, but I meant for this problem specifically.  Clarified it in my answer.

Comment: If it's the fastest solution for this problem, it's not because it accesses C libraries. Many parts of Python do that.

Comment: Of course they do, but regex for this problem allows you to spend very little time in the python intepreter - I just did it in 3 lines of python code, and all the rest is done in C.

Answer (score 2):

Use a 2D `list` and some loops.

```
instring = 'oooooooooooooxxxxxxxxxxxxoooooooooooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxoooooooooooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxoooooooooooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxoooooooooooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxoooooooooooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxooooooooooooox'

board = []
for x in range(13):
    board.append(instring[x::13])
board = list(zip(*board))
```

If a row has a winner, print the winner:

```
>>> for row in range(13):
...     if len(set(board[row]))-2: print(board[row][0])
...
o
```

If a column has a winner, print the winner:

```
>>> for row in range(13):
...     if len(set(list(zip(*board))[row]))-2: print(board[row][0])
...
```

If the `\`-shaped diagonal has a winner, print the winner:

```
>>> if len(set(board[i][i] for i in range(13)))==1:
...     print(board[0][0])
...
```

If the `/`-shaped diagonal has a winner, print the winner:

```
>>> if len(set(board[i][i] for i in range(-1, -14, -1)))==1:
...     print(board[0][12])
...
```

Comment: This code did not work for me as is.  What version of python are you using perhaps?  "row" isn't accessible outside of this context: any(len(set(board[row]))-2 for row in range(13))

Comment: That's odd; it worked for me yesterday but not right now. I'll edit it.